# Openlayers 5 hide layer

Tags: openlayers

How can you show/hide a layer (not a feature) in openlayers 5?

There is a visible parameter to the TileLayer object i'm working with, but changing that value does nothing.  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Tile-TileLayer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices

**When instanciating the layer**

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

var osm = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM(),
  visible: false
});
var map = new Map({
  layers: [osm],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

**After instanciation of the layer**

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

var osm = new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM()
});
var map = new Map({
  layers: [osm],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
osm.setVisible(false);
```

`setVisible` method is inherited from http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Base-BaseLayer.html

PS: At the moment, the API is more readable in [version 4.6.5 of the docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.layer.Tile.html). as you have all inherited properties shown in one place.
Since version 5.0, [a refactoring of the docs](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8448) related to TypeScript/Typedoc is ongoing but not finished, hence the poor readability at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, i need your option #2, but i guess what was tripping me up is that this doesn't work for me:  mapObj.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
          if (itemGUID === lyr.WMSLayerGUID) {
            lyr.visible = !lyr.visible;  
          }
        });

Comment: lyr.visible is always 'undefined', even after i use the 'setvisible' function

Comment: Related to bad use of Openlayers in your loop, not to setVisible...

Comment: `mapObj.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
  if (itemGUID === lyr.get('WMSLayerGUID')) {
    lyr.setVisible(!lyr.getVisible());
  }
});`

Comment: Try to log variables e.g `mapObj.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
  console.log(itemGUID, lyr.get('WMSLayerGUID'), lyr.getVisible());
});`

Comment: No you're wrong, the for loop and the if statement both work fine.  i don't need the get function, for some reason you're assuming i'm not hitting setVisible, i am.  Forget the if statement. Even outside that, lyr.visible is always undefined

Comment: I was wrong maybe (tried to guess only from your code and misunderstood it seems) `lyr.visible` will always be undefined and it's normal. Property `visible` is only accessible via `lyr.getVisible()`